# How to get one end of a path to fade out using Material node?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to work out the best way to get one end of a path to fade out using a Material node, regardless of its axis, position or shape.

Below is a screenshot of what I've tried and what I'm hoping to achieve, for clarity.

[image]

If I shape the path into a curve, the fade moves depending on what position the curve is on the axis.

To add, I’m using a Bevel Object to display the material. The intention is also that the fade would adapt, and position itself where the End factor value is.

Comment: so, even if you curve the first path, you get the fade moving from the tip to the center of it?